# Not able to get options listed in select input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a select input component with data

```
const haulTypes=['Long Haul',
'Short Haul',
]
```

I am using a useEffect to load this in a select input option field

```
const [haulTypes,setHaulTypes]=useState([]);
useEffect(() => {

  const AirType= haulTypes.reduce(
    (acc, item, index) => [
        ...acc,
        { key: index + 1, label: `${item}`, value:item },
    ],
    [{ key: 0, label: "Select Type", value: "" }]
  );
  setHaulTypes(AirType)
}, [])
```

but i am not getting the desired options array expected what is the possible solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you want to use `hualTypes` in your option field, just use `map` function in the options, there is no need of `useEffect`

```
<select>
   {haulTypes.map((el) => {
      return <option>{el}</option>;
   })}
</select>
```